# How to make java run a .sql file in MS Access

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access, database-connection

So What am trying to do is to make java read my .sql file and then create the connection for the MS Access and run the .sql file into the MS Access database. 
I wrote the sql file myself. For now it only has `Create Database IF NOT EXISTS Students;`. I want to run this in Ms access using java
Can you just tell me how i can do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify how this .sql file was created.

Comment: @GordThompson Please see the above edited question

Comment: `Create Database` is not supported by [Access SQL Data Definition Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn125729.aspx)

Comment: @HansUp Ok so i have to manually create the database into MS Access then i will be able to run other sql statement like create table and so on?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do what you want using Java.  I simply hoped you might appreciate the warning about `Create Database`

Answer (score 1):

If your .sql file has each complete DDL statement on a separate line, like so

```sql
CREATE TABLE tblStudents (ID AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT(255))
INSERT INTO tblStudents (FirstName) VALUES ('Gord')
```

then the required Java code could be something as simple as this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String connStr = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/Students.accdb" +
            ";newdatabaseversion=V2010";
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
        try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
            String sqlFilePath = "C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/myTest.sql";
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sqlFilePath))) {
                for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                    line = line.trim();
                    System.out.println(line);  // echo to console
                    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                        s.executeUpdate(line);  // run SQL statement
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```